# Globalprotect VPN batch file or C# code

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, batch-file, vpn

Hi I am trying to connect to a VPN network using GlobalProtect VPN client. I can do that using the UI but I would like this to be automated. In another project where I was using Sonicwall Netextender, I created a batch file which I was calling from my C# code so I would connect to a VPN by calling the batch file, do some operations and disconnect using another batch file. I am trying to find a similar way to achieve it using Globalprotect. The command line arguments which I was using with Netextender does not seem to work with the PanGPA.exe.  Any ideas how I could do that? I am not having any luck with the batch file so far.
The netextender batch file is:

```
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender\
NECLI connect -s 122.254.213.256 -d DNAME -u UNAME -p PASSWORD
```

Comment: Did you try : `cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender\"` ?

Comment: As I said "I am trying to find a similar way to achieve it using Globalprotect". Netextender is not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such automation possible with globalprotect VPN client

Answer (score 4):

**Update: just use OpenConnect v8.00 or newer.** GlobalProtect support has been incorporated into the "official" OpenConnect builds [as of v8.00](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/changelog.html). So GP support will Just Work™ with a recent official build.

———

You cannot do this with the official GP client. However, I have recently extended the fantastic open-source VPN client [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) to support the PAN GlobalProtect VPN, both in its SSL-VPN and IPsec/ESP modes. It acts just like a native client and you can run it from the command line in a fully automated manner.

This is a [work in progress](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2016-October/004035.html), but I've been using it for real work already and it works very well for me. **Having other people test it would be awesome and I welcome your feedback!**

You'll need to build the `globalprotect` branch from this repository:
https://github.com/dlenski/openconnect

... and then run it like this to test it (you can omit the `--certificate` part if your VPN doesn't use a client certificate):

```
echo password | openconnect --user username --passwd-on-stdin \
              --protocol=gp [--certificate=my_cert_with_pk.pem] \
              gp-gateway-server.company.com --dump -vvv
```

(I have not yet tested *this build* under Windows, but the official OpenConnect builds are all Windows-compatible and there is nothing particularly special about this one.)

Comment: How can I build this repo on windows?

Comment: @kizilsu, I don't use Windows, especially not for software development. Eventually it should get incorporated into the Windows GUI (see  https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect-gui/issues/158).

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat "hacked" workaround by virtually clicking the "Connect" button solved the problem for me on Windows. This can be accomplished using NirSoft's "NirCmd" command-line tool *(1)* using the following command:

```
NIRCMD win child class "#32770" sendmsg id 1160 0xF5 0 0
```

Effectively, this sends a BM_CLICK window message to the button, where "#32770" is the class name of its dialog window, "1160" (decimal) is the ItemID of the "Connect" button and 0xF5, according to *(2)*, is the numerical Win32 API constant for the BM_CLICK message. This simulates the normal user action as if s/he would click the button manually. Clicking the button again (manually or by calling the same command) results in a disconnect of the established connection.

In my case, there was only a single connection configured — different things might happen if there are multiple connections in the list as the user might have to make a decision on which one to use.

Be careful, as the class name and ItemID values might be different on another machine or version/build of the GlobalProtect agent. These values worked for me as I figured them out using the "WinExplorer" tool by NirSoft *(3)* by capturing the button control and looking up its details. At least, both the class name and ItemID seem to be persistent, which means that a program crash, termination or reboot do not result in any changes.

**References:**
*(1)* https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
*(2)* http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/b/bm_click.html
*(3)* https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winexp.html